# How to select value A or both A and B but not B in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tableA:

```
column1     column2
name1       A
name1       B
```

In column1, **name1** can have 2 values in column2: **A** or **B**.

I want to select like this:

```
select *
from tableA
where ??
```

The condition is when column2 is equal to A **or** both A and B, but not B **alone**. Is this possible?

What I expect in the condition of the query:

```
column1     column2
name1       A
```

Or

```
column1     column2
name1       A
name1       B
```

What I do not want:

```
column1     column2
name1       B
```

Comment: The first and second case (a or a+b) can be treated as the same case - so basically - `where column2 = 'a'` covers your desired conditions completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specification is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.column2 = 'A' or
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.column1 = t.column1 and t2.column2 = 'A');
```

This can actually be simplified to:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.column1 = t.column1 and t2.column2 = 'A');
```

If you just want the names with this property, then:

```
select distinct t.column
from t
where t.column1 = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`

```
select *
  from tableA a
 where exists ( select 1 from tableA where column1 = a.column1 and column2 = 'A' );
```

For current case, even without adding `column1 = a.column1 and` part, you can get the desired results.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1d87e068ce28a73272dc9b08895c925a)</kbd>